# Program isn't starting

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet-recovery

The app would launch fine. However, one day after it was working as expected the app would not launch anymore. I have no idea if the files have become or what has happened. I have disabled my antivirus completely (which in this case is windows defender) and have even rolled back windows version. I've given the necessary permissions for the wallet to run and open as well, but it doesn't. I will also mention that as I run Bitcoin Core, I see the process tree rise up to the top in task manager and after around 2 seconds, it disappears with no evidence of the app actually launching. Keep in mind that I never let the computer shut down without safely closing the Bitcoin Core wallet. Please help as I really don't want to lose access to my bitcoin wallet.

Comment: Have you looked at the last 10-50 lines of %APPDATA%\Bitcoin\debug.log? What is in there?

Comment: The last thing that was ever logged was on the day 10/04 which I'm guessing is the last day the waller actually worked. Nothing else after that is logged no matter how many times I try to launch the wallet to this day. Any idea?

Comment: What appears or happens if you open a command prompt window and type `cd \Program Files\Bitcoin` then `bitcoin-qt`. What messages appear when you type `cd \Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon` and then `bitcoind` or   `bitcoin-wallet info`

Comment: When executing `bitcoin-qt.exe` the windows blue circle faintly appears next to the mouse cursor. No new process is started up during this time though. It says block files have been previously pruned when `bitcoind.exe` was executed. Then it tells me to use -reindex or -reindex-chainstate to recover. Which one should I choose? When executing `bitcoin-wallet info` it says failed to load database path (then lists a path) followed by saying data is not in a recognized format.

Comment: Sounds like some data files were corrupted. I would restore the Bitcoin data from a recent backup.

Comment: Yep, was doing that until my ssd said nope and killed itself. Isn't recognized by any os anymore. 